# `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 4)` with `scipy.stats.linregress`

Tags: python, scipy, linear-regression

I know that this error message (`ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 4)`) appears when more variables are set to values than a function returns.

`scipy.stats.linregress` returns 5 values according to the scipy documentation (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html).

Here is a short, reproducible example of a working call, and then a failed call, to `linregress`:

What could account for difference and why is the second one poorly called?

```
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = np.random.random(10)
    y = np.random.random(10)
    print(x,y)
    slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(x,y)


'''
Code above works
Code below fails
'''

    X = np.asarray([[-15.93675813],
 [-29.15297922],
 [ 36.18954863],
 [ 37.49218733],
 [-48.05882945],
 [ -8.94145794],
 [ 15.30779289],
 [-34.70626581],
 [  1.38915437],
 [-44.38375985],
 [  7.01350208],
 [ 22.76274892]])

    Y = np.asarray( [[  2.13431051],
 [  1.17325668],
 [ 34.35910918],
 [ 36.83795516],
 [  2.80896507],
 [  2.12107248],
 [ 14.71026831],
 [  2.61418439],
 [  3.74017167],
 [  3.73169131],
 [  7.62765885],
 [ 22.7524283 ]])

    print(X,Y) # The array initialization succeeds, if both arrays are print out


    for i in range(1,len(X)):
        slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = (stats.linregress(X[0:i,:], y = Y[0:i,:]))
```

Comment: can you post the complete error message and stacktrace?

Comment: The shape of your X, and Y are: (12, 1) but what you need is (12, ).

Comment: also, which value of `i` causes the issue?

Comment: For pandas users with the same error: use `df.pop('value')` to return (R, ) shape for `linregression`. This returns the 5 values `slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err` expected in the docs and this question

Answer (score 9):

Your problem originates from slicing the `X` and `Y` arrays. Also you do not need the `for` loop. Use the following instead and it should work.

```
slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(X[:,0], Y[:,0])
```

Comment: They may *want* the `for` loop still (hard to say).  But the solution *is* to change `[...,:]` to `[...,0]`.

Comment: I assume s/he has used the `for` loop to take care of the arrays' shape. If the correct slicing is used, the `for` loop with not be needed.

Comment: I thought they were trying to get the results of *n* different regressions, each considering one additional element in X/Y.

Comment: @jedwards Yes, you're right. It is my intention to get the results of n different regressions. What about the documentation indicates that the solution is to change `[...,:]` to `[...,0]`, however?

Comment: @jedwards From the docs,                                                                             x, y : array_like
Two sets of measurements. Both arrays should have the same length. If only x is given (and y=None), then it must be a two-dimensional array where one dimension has length 2. The two sets of measurements are then found by splitting the array along the length-2 dimension.

Comment: @Muno, because you are creating your arrays using lists where each element is itself a list.  This will result in `X` and `Y` being two-dimensional arrays, each having `.shape = (12,1)`.  But the function doesn't expect two dimensional arrays, it expects one-dimensional arrays (e.g. `.shape = (12,)`).  So you need to extract a single column using `[...,0]`.  When you use `[...,:]`, you're extracting *all* columns, so the inputs are *still* each two-dimensional (12,1) arrays.

Answer (score 2):

The issue stems from the fact that your input to `np.asarray` are lists of single elements lists.

Thus, `X` and `Y` both have shape of (12,1):

```
print(X.shape)  # (12, 1)   [or (12L, 1L), depending on version]
print(Y.shape)  # (12, 1)
```

Note that these are each *two-dimensional* arrays.  Even though one of the dimensions is 1, they're still considered two-dimensional.

Now consider this way of creating an array:

```
x = np.asarray([1,2,3,4,5])
print(x.shape)  # (5,)
```

Note in this case, since we passed a list of integers to `asarray`, we got a one-dimensional array.

Your function, when called with two variables, needs each to be one-dimensional arrays.  So, you can either create the arrays initially as one-dimensional:

For example, by hand:

```
X = np.asarray([-15.93675813,
                -29.15297922,
                 36.18954863,
                 37.49218733,
                -48.05882945,
                 -8.94145794,
                 15.30779289,
                -34.70626581,
                  1.38915437,
                -44.38375985,
                  7.01350208,
                 22.76274892])
```

Or by list comprehension:

```
y_data = [[  2.13431051],
          [  1.17325668],
          [ 34.35910918],
          [ 36.83795516],
          [  2.80896507],
          [  2.12107248],
          [ 14.71026831],
          [  2.61418439],
          [  3.74017167],
          [  3.73169131],
          [  7.62765885],
          [ 22.7524283 ]]
Y = np.asarray([e[0] for e in y_data])
```

Or by slicing:

```
Y = np.asarray([[  2.13431051],
                [  1.17325668],
                [ 34.35910918],
                [ 36.83795516],
                [  2.80896507],
                [  2.12107248],
                [ 14.71026831],
                [  2.61418439],
                [  3.74017167],
                [  3.73169131],
                [  7.62765885],
                [ 22.7524283 ]])
Y = Y[:,0]
```

All three methods would result in you having `X` and `Y` of shape `(12,)` (one-dimensional):

```
print(X.shape)  # (12,)
print(Y.shape)  # (12,)
```

Then, you could use your loop as:

```
for i in range(3,len(X)):
    slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(X[0:i], y = Y[0:i])
    print(slope)
```

Note, I started the loop at 3, it's the first value that "makes sense".

**Or**, you could keep your arrays unmodified as two-dimensional, and just fix the slicing syntax inside your loop:

```
for i in range(3,len(X)):
    slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(X[0:i,0], y = Y[0:i,0])
    print(slope)
```

This is the method that was suggested in the answer I was commenting to.

Answer (score 0):

After several attempts, the following worked for me:

```
slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(X[:], Y[:])
```