# Python showing "too many values to unpack"

Tags: python, linear-regression

I am trying to build a linear regression model to calculate whether infant mortality rates affect life expectancy or not. I am using Google Collab to perform it. Here is my code:

```
x = data.loc[(data['Country'] == 'Bangladesh'), ['infant deaths']]
y = data.loc[(data['Country'] == 'Bangladesh'), ['Life expectancy ']]

slope, intercept, r, p, std_err = stats.linregress(x, y)

def myfunc(x):
 return slope * x + intercept

mymodel = list(map(myfunc, x))

plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.plot(x, slope * x + intercept)
plt.ylim(ymin=0, ymax=2000)
plt.xlim(xmin=0, xmax=200)
plt.xlabel("infact deaths")
plt.ylabel ("Life expectancy")
plt.show()
```

However, I get an error message like this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-32392bb3a878> in <module>()
      2 y = data.loc[(data['Country'] == 'Bangladesh'), ['Life expectancy ']]
      3 
----> 4 slope, intercept, r, p, std_err = stats.linregress(x, y)
      5 
      6 def myfunc(x):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scipy/stats/_stats_mstats_common.py in linregress(x, y)
    114 
    115     # average sum of squares:
--> 116     ssxm, ssxym, ssyxm, ssym = np.cov(x, y, bias=1).flat
    117     r_num = ssxym
    118     r_den = np.sqrt(ssxm * ssym)

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 4)
```

I am confident that my naming of the columns is correct. I have also imported all the libraries or modules. Please help me find a solution.

Comment: What if you use such construct ``x = data.loc[data['Country'] == 'Bangladesh', 'infant deaths']`` to return a series rather than a dataframe (same for y)? It is likely that linregress will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Similar question was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38725018/valueerror-too-many-values-to-unpack-expected-4-with-scipy-stats-linregres). Looks like your x and y shapes are not sound with ones required by `lingress`. Consider expecting them using `.shape`, for example.